# Building a MEMS Microphone Monitor System

Tags: preamp, monitor, breakout, mems-microphone

While I've never used a breakout board when building an electret mic, I have used the small Spark Fun 09068 and Cinimark admp401 boards for MEMS mics. They seem to work with a 9v battery box I built for electret mics but they're very hot. I reduced the voltage on one with a buck convertor to 3.3v and it seems to work pretty well into a personal headphone amp.

I'm a real beginner at this and never really understood the distinction between the mics, their power requirements, power source and just what makes a microphone PCB a "breakout board". Is the goal to bring the output to line level? What I'm attempting, with some success, is using a mems mic to provide a simple wired, in ear monitor system for an unplugged acoustic guitar.

I realize these are really dumb questions and if anyone could help or direct me somewhere with beginner level tutorials I'd appreciate it. At 76 I'm not looking for a new career but as a still active musician I'd like to understand this a bit better.

Comment: Sparkfun 09068 is an LCD display, is that the right number?

Comment: Every electronic component should come with a data sheet describing what it does and how it does it. Quality stuff can have very detailed ones (but sometimes not so detailed); random stuff from ebay or aliexpress can have none and you have to completely guess (serious engineers don't buy from ebay or aliexpress); [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/ADMP401.pdf) I found their data sheet for an ADMP401 from Sparkfun. On page 3 you can see it is designed for a power supply of 1.5 to 3.3 volts.

Comment: A breakout board generally means a thing that makes it easier to make connections to the device it supports.  Beyond that, everything will be very specific to the exact part you're talking about.